# Дообучение gpt-j

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, gpt

Сам процесс обучения мне ясень. Есть ли какие-нибудь примеры удачного и неудачного обучения. Скинте ссылки кто знает такие примеры. Я хочу создать модель которая будет создавать новые уникальные истории одной тематики(шутки, морская тема, десткие рассказы, тема будет подобной одной из этих, пока сам не решил какая имена). Набор обучаемых данных 1000 историй, от 30 до 200 слов(на английском). Есть ли какие-нибудь советы для такой задачи обучения. Если есть другие более актуальные нейросети, пожалуйста напишите об них.